# Is this because of USB device that Device Manager is flickering every 2 seconds?

Tags: windows-10, usb, device-manager, midi

Device Manager on my PC (using Windows 10) suddenly shows high consumption of CPU power and is refreshing itself every couple of seconds. In addition I no longer receive input from MIDI devices connected via USB cable. This happened just suddenly, without me attaching new devices or updating anything.

I read that such behavior of a Device Manager is an indication of its unsuccessful retries to install a (USB?) device. So I started disconnecting and reconnecting my USB devices one by one (I have several, this a music arrangement PC), but Device Manager is still flickering and consuming much CPU. I must admit I didn't restart the machine after reconnecting USB devices but I assume because of their PnP nature this should not be necessary.

Now I wonder if it can be anything else that affects Device Manager. But what? And how can I detect it? But first of all I am trying to understand if such behavior can only be caused by USB or it can be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: yes, this is because of USB and this can be cured. At least in my case.

What helped is an excellent freeware tool [USB Device Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) that showed all registered system devices, active and disconnected. Since most of USB devices are plug-in-play, then it's usually OK to delete them from Windows registry (not just disable, delete). I did that leaving only mouse and keyboard, restarted my machine and after re-connecting USB devices all my MIDI instruments worked fine and Device Manager stopped flickering trying to install a new device.